# Android Device: Connecting to iBeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon

This is a general query that I have because I have seen contrasting posts about the ways people have implemented it.
My use case is that I want my Android device to connect to iBeacon whenever it is in range, and start a particular app.
How do I go about it? I am not looking for code, in particular, a general direction of how to go about it would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

- **You can program an app to auto-launch itself when a beacon is detected.**  If this app is already installed on an Android device, it can send a notification or simply appear when the beacon is seen.  The free and open source Android Beacon Library has tools that let you do this.  See [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html)

Here's what you cannot do:

- **If you do not have a custom app installed on a phone, then you can not make the phone do anything to respond to a beacon.**  Once upon a time, it was possible on many phones with Google Play Services to make a beacon detection prompt a user to install your app.  Google, however, discontinued this feature of their Nearby service in December 2018.

Comment: For those who are looking for a sample application:
https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference
PS: David Young is one of the contributors.